# TO_TIMESTAMP using POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, numeric

****How can I convert numeric to time PAYMENTDATE****

```
SELECT BANKCODE, PAYMENTDATE,
Current_Date, 
TO_TIMESTAMP (PAYMENTDATE)::VARCHAR,'YYYYMMDD',
PAYMENTDATE::VARCHAR,
--TO_CHAR (TO_TIMESTAMP (PAYMENTDATE),'YYYYMMDD'),
SUM (CASE WHEN (TABLETYPE='ET') AND (TRANSACTIONTYPE=2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"OGS",
SUM (CASE WHEN (TABLETYPE='ET') AND (TRANSACTIONTYPE=2) THEN APPROVEDPRICE ELSE 0 END)/100 "OGS GELIR ",
SUM (CASE WHEN (TABLETYPE='ET') AND (TRANSACTIONTYPE=20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"HGS",
SUM (CASE WHEN (TABLETYPE='ET') AND (TRANSACTIONTYPE=20) THEN APPROVEDPRICE ELSE 0 END)/100 "HGS GELIR ",
SUM (CASE WHEN (TABLETYPE='EFV') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"IGB",
SUM (CASE WHEN (TABLETYPE='EFV') THEN APPROVEDPRICE ELSE 0 END)/100 "IGB GELIR ",
COUNT(*)"TOTAL",
SUM (APPROVEDPRICE/100)"TUM GELIR"
FROM kvk.sap_transactions_view
WHERE BANKCODE IN ('1','2','4','6','7')
AND PAYMENTDATE BETWEEN '20210801' AND '20211001'

GROUP BY BANKCODE, PAYMENTDATE
ORDER BY BANKCODE;
```

Comment: Don't store numbers instead of dates to begin with. That's a serious bug. Almost all databases have a `date` type. Using the correct type makes it a *lot* easier to migrate schemas, data and queries from one database to another and avoids the data quality, indexing, space and functionality problems caused by using text or numbers

Comment: What exactly do you store inside that `numeric` column? And what exactly is the output you want? Unrelated, but: the `sum(case .. end)` can also be written as `count(*) filter (where ...)`

Comment: PAYMENTDATE is a numeric column. I want to equlize CURRET_DATE = PAYMENTDATE . However, PAYMENTDATE format numeric, not a DATE .

Answer (score 2):

I found the correct syntax:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(PAYMENTDATE::VARCHAR,'YYYYMMDD')::DATE
```

Comment: You can can simplify your expression to `to_date(PAYMENTDATE::VARCHAR,'YYYYMMDD')`. But you should really fix your data model and change the column's type to `date`